# How to start substrate-node-template and substrate-front-end-template remotely?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-front-end, blockchain

I want to start my own blockchain. I try to start [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) and [substrate-front-end-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template) remotely, but there is guide instructions only for local machine. I installed and compiled node and frontend on linux dedicated server. The question is:

1. How to start node remotely and make it run even when I close the ssh panel.
2. How to make frontend find the node? Because when I open the link *somesite.com* - it tries to connect the node all the time? and all the time gets an errors with no connections.
   Frontend error: 
       **Error Connecting to Substrate

       Connection to websocket 'wss://127.0.0.1:9944/' failed.**

   Log from my node-template:
   **2023-07-19 13:38:51 Accepting new connection 1/100

   2023-07-19 13:38:51 HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Parse(Method))

   2023-07-19 13:38:54 ✨ Imported #140 (0xfca2…389f)**

   Commands I use:
   ./target/release/node-template 
   --base-path /tmp/alice 
   --chain local 
   --alice 
   --port 30333 
   --ws-port 9944 
   --rpc-port 9933 
   --node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 
   --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" 
   --validator 
   --unsafe-ws-external 
   --unsafe-rpc-external 
   --rpc-cors=all 
   --rpc-methods=Unsafe

Comment: I found decision - in production/development.json need to specify **ws**://server_ip_address instead of **wss**://server_ip_address . And in browser it should run without **https** (only **http**). Now I'm looking how to fix it to run over https server (not http)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How to start node remotely and make it run even when I close the ssh panel.

To start the node remotely then assuming you've already built the substrate-node-template in the folder /opt/substrate-node-template and assuming your username and IP address is `linuxuser@x.x.x.x` and that you've setup public key authentication for ssh (passwordless login) as described in [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/use-public-key-authentication-with-ssh/)
then you could run the following, which uses the steps mentioned [here](https://www.linuxtechi.com/execute-linux-commands-remote-system-over-ssh/) or to remotely run a shell script with executable permissions.

```bash
ssh linuxuser@x.x.x.x "cd /opt/substrate-node-template && ./target/release/node-template --dev"
```

To make substrate-node-template run even when you close the ssh panel, run it as a Systemd process like they mention [here](https://docs.substrate.io/deploy/deployment-options/) under the "Linux servers" heading. The following guides are provided reference:

- Use a Systemd service to run a Polkadot validator node by following [this](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-systemd) guide
- Use a Systemd service to run a Moonbeam collator node by following [this](https://docs.moonbeam.network/node-operators/networks/run-a-node/systemd/) guide.

If you do not want to use a Systemd process then you could use the [`tmux`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) program or the [`screen`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server) program to run and detach from multiple sessions so they keep running.

> How to make frontend find the node? Because when I open the link somesite.com - it tries to connect the node all the time? and all the time gets an errors with no connections

- Check that the substrate-node-template is actually running and configure the CLI options to securely expose it using the default ports or explicitly configure the port numbers to use with CLI options `--port`, `--rpc-port`, and `--ws-port`. Also check that you are running other CLI options like the following in a development environment only to expose it `--unsafe-ws-external`, `--unsafe-rpc-external`, `--rpc-cors=all`, `--rpc-methods=Unsafe`.
- Configure your linux dedicated server firewall to accept connections on those ports
- Check that you have updated your browser to the latest version and that you have disabled any browser plugins like [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5966/connecting-to-a-chain-on-ws-localhost-with-polkadot-js-app-fails-when-running) that may interfere with the connection
- Check that your substrate-front-end-template is configured to try to connect to the substrate-node-template using the default or custom ports that you are using it with
- Take a screenshot or copy/paste the error shown in the web browser console and share it with us here

Comment: Error from my node like this:
    HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Parse(Method)) 
And error from frontend like this:
    Error Connecting to Substrate
    Connection to websocket 'wss://127.0.0.1:9944/' failed.

Comment: Try running it with `--ws-port 9944` instead of `--ws-port 9945`. 
If you followed an official substrate-node-template guides like https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/simulate-network/, they use all default ports, but they explicitly ask you to use port `9945` with `--ws-port 9945 \` (instead of the default port `9944`). By doing that it presents an hidden challenge for newcomers as they don't mention it's a non-default port. It's not the first time I've seen someone encounter this issue, so I'd recommend updating the docs to mention when an example uses a non-default port.

Comment: Since those official examples use non-default port `9945` instead of default port `9944`, users get stumped and can't automatically connect their node when they go to https://polkadot.js.org/apps, where if you choose to connect to your Local Node it is pre-populated with the default port 9944 (i.e. https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws://127.0.0.1:9944). It's also why the substrate-front-end-template by default connects to port `9944` https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template/blob/main/src/config/development.json#L2

Comment: It is still not working. I change the port, so now there is no error in node terminal. But it is still an error in frontend. The same error: **Error Connecting to Substrate
Connection to websocket 'ws://127.0.0.1:9944/' failed.**. And browser console shows me this: **logger.js:56 2023-07-20 12:48:41          API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: Abnormal Closure
overrideMethod @ console.js:213
Gs @ logger.js:56
error @ logger.js:115
Sc.__internal__onSocketClose @ index.js:71
Show 1 more frame
index.js:307 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9944/' failed: **

Comment: can you help me, if I give you all access? I study substrate almost 2 months and still cannot run even this simple project.

Comment: did you update your linux dedicated server firewall to accept connections on the appropriate port 9944 instead of 9945?

Comment: yes, It accepts all ports. Maybe I should write something in **production.json** file except this rows **{
  "PROVIDER_SOCKET": "ws://localhost:9944"
} 
**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147352/discussion-between---and-luke-schoen).

Answer (score 0):

I opened browser with http://somedomen.com (not https:// like earlier) and now it works fine with -**ws**-port. Too bad that substrate doesn't support --**wss**-port, becouse I still dont know how to make it work with ssl